# Reduce function in Python

Tags: python

I used the [reduce](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce) function to multiply all the elements of a list as follows.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,l) #returns 120
```

Now, suppose I have a list, `l = [1,'apple',2,'apple','apple']`, and I want to count how many times the word "apple" appears in the list. Is this possible using reduce?

I'm aware I can use `l.count('apple')`, but I want to know if a reduce solution is possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can u give an example please ?

Comment: One thing's for certain: if you want to ask a homework-related reduce question, you should call yourself Jill and not James (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139168/implementing-reduce-in-python).  Jill gets 5 answers, James gets -5 votes.. and yes, I recognize this one's genuinely written in a better way.  Is simply funny, is all.

Comment: ha!  that is awesome (and depressing, and hopelessly predictable).  i promise i just turned on the computer...

Comment: @DSM: It's also not the same question.

Comment: @sepp2k: yep, it's a different question -- and, as I said, better-written, as this one mentions being aware of alternate ways to achieve the goal.  It'd be funnier if it were exactly the same question, of course, which got such a wildly different response, but same author, same assignment, and same Python function within two hours isn't bad for a lazy afternoon.  YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x + (y == 'apple'), l, 0)
```

But as you mentioned yourself, there is no need to use `reduce` here. It is likely that it will be slower than any other counting method and the intention is not immediately clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest using an initializer (the extra `0` at the end of the call to reduce), so you only need to convert the second argument:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x + (1 if y=='apple' else 0), [1,'apple',2,'apple','apple'], 0)
```

Or you can reduce something that has been transformed by a map into 0 and 1:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda x: 1 if x=='apple' else 0,  [1,'apple',2,'apple','apple']))
```

But there are lots of ways to make this more natural:

- use list comprehensions rather than reduce
- use the operators package instead of defining your own function for addition
- user itertools

(And the counter suggestion above is really cool - I don't think I even knew that existed.)

A simpler (but not very efficient) approach would be:

```
len([x for x in [1,'apple',2,'apple','apple'] if x=='apple'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l
[1, 'apple', 2, 'apple', 'apple']
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + (1 if y == 'apple' else 0), l, 0)
3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> l = [1,'apple',2,'apple','apple']
>>> reduce(lambda s, i: s+1 if i == "apple" else s, l, 0)
3
```

You can simplify `s+1 if i == "apple" else s` part to just `s + (i == "apple")`, but I think implicit bool => int conversions are cryptic. But using reduce for this job is cryptic anyway :).

Answer (score 1):

If you use a "real" function instead of a lambda function solutions to problems like this usually become much clearer:

```
def count_apples(acc, v):
   if v == 'apple':
      return acc+1
   else:
      return acc

l = [1,'apple',2,'apple','apple']
print reduce(count_apples, l, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import mul
from time import clock

n= 10000

li = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    x = reduce(mul,li)
print clock()-te


te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    y = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b,li)
print clock()-te


print x==y
```

result

```
0.0616016840129
0.124420003101
True
```

.

```
li = [1,78,2,2,12,45,1,2,8,1,2,5,4,2]


te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    x = li.count(2)
print clock()-te

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    y = sum(1 for a in li if a==2)
print clock()-te

te = clock()
for i in xrange(n):
    z = len([a for a in li if a==2])
print clock()-te

print x==y==z
```

produces

```
0.0110332458455
0.0428308625817
0.0518741907142
True
```

Comment: Hey eyquem. These timings are interesting, but the question wasn't about performance, it was about how "count" could be implemented with `reduce`. You should only post something as an answer if it specifically addresses the question. I know this was too big to put in a comment, but that simply means it's not a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 0):

## Custom reduce function in python

```
def my_reduce(func,sequence) :
    res=sequence[0]
    for variable in sequence[1:]:
        res =func(variable,res)

    return res


def my_sum(a,b):
    return a+b


seq=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(str(my_reduce(my_sum,seq)))
```

Comment: Output will be 15